# How to override "Selectors should not contain IDs" rule in SublimeLinter-CSSLint?

Tags: json, macos, sublimetext3, sublimelinter, csslint

Entering `csslint --list-rules` into the terminal, I see the following rule:

```
ids
  Selectors should not contain IDs.
```

So, in my `SublimeLinter.sublime-settings` user prefs file, I've tried setting "ids" to `false`, `true`, `"none"`, `"ignore"`, `"exclude"`, and `""` in the below code structure, but to no effect.

```
{
  "user": {
    "linters": {
      "csslint": {
        "ids": /* WHAT TO PUT HERE? */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not easily finding documentation for how to calibrate the `ids` settings. Anyone know? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the way it's meant to be instead, but I found a solution by adding `"ids"` to the linter's `"ignored"` property, rather than by tuning an `"ids"` property itself:

```
{
  "user": {
    "linters": {
      "csslint": {
        "ignored": ["ids"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's 'ignore' instead of 'ignored', check the documentation here.. https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Command-line-interface#options

Comment: @SandeshDamkondwar: I believe `ignore` is for the CLI only, not the settings JSON.